# by/from/of in the sentence "a comment from John"

Tags: prepositions

I was replying an email sent by a friend and I wrote
"Thanks Mark, interesting the comment from John!"

Basically I was trying to say that John made a good comment about a magazine article.

I feel I keep using italian structures in my brain... but they sound unnatural in English: what preposition or sentence should I have used?

Comment: Welcome to ELL and thanks for your question! Thinking in a new language is the key to speaking it well. If you look up the word [**comment**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/comment?s=ts) in your dictionary, you will find some examples. What prepositions do they use? Our [Help Center](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help) pages will show you how to write a good question. We hope you will ask more of them.

Answer (score 2):

I think a more natural way to say it would be:

> *Thanks, Mark. That was an interesting comment from John!*

The present tense could also be used:

> *Thanks, Mark. That's an interesting comment from John!*

The reason you can use either past or present tense is because:

- The comment was made and sent in the past (so past tense is okay); however,
- You still find the comment interesting (so present tense is okay, too)

You can also move the word *interesting* to the end:

> *Thanks, Mark. That comment from John is/was interesting.*